# Using SOQL, how can I tell which dashboards have not been used in the past year?

Tags: soql, reporting, dashboard

The title says it all, really - I am looking at hundreds of dashboards (literally) and I want to find the ones that aren't being used and kill them. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this, don't think there is a way to do it in SOQL as Refresh Date is still not available in SOQL, but you may be able to query across reports to do something similar to the following: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004237

Comment: This worked, along with an export to Excel and a pivot table - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do it only using `SQOL` but the `Analytics API` offers an easy way to do so.

Build your request in this manner

```
public HttpResponse getDashboardStatus(String dashboardID){
    String salesforceInstance = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    String baseURL = salesforceInstance +
        + '/services/data/v31.0/analytics/dashboards/' + dashboardID + '';

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndPoint(baseURL);
    request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    request.setHeader('X-PrettyPrint','1');

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    return response;
}
```

This would typically return a response such as

Dashboard is invalid

```
[ {
    "errorCode" : "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message" : "The running user for this dashboard is inactive. Your system administrator should select an active user for this dashboard."
}]
```

Dashboard is valid, and individual component status

```
"componentData" : [ {

    .............<<Skipped>>

    "status" : {
        "dataStatus" : "DATA",
        "errorCode" : null,
        "errorMessage" : null,
        "errorSeverity" : null,
        "refreshDate" : "2014-08-02T11:33:23.000+0000",
        "refreshStatus" : "IDLE"
    }
}]
```

The response will tell you which dashboards are invalid and also the `refreshDate` so you can figure out which ones are stale.